# How to force the canvas to use only a portion of the area to draw text when extending a TextView

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am creating a custom view that extends the TextView. What I need is a couple of labels on the left handside and another checker on the right hand side of the TextView.

So I can draw those labels and then save the canvas and translate it right so that the text can be drawn beside the bitmaps. This is how I am doing that.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0, top, paint);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, bitmap1_width, top, paint);

canvas.save();
canvas.translate(bitmap1_width + bitmap2_width, 0);
```

Here I want to call super.onDraw but ask it to use the width so that the widths of the two bitmaps and the checker are subtracted.

Then I am can call my

```
canvas.drawBitmap(checker, checkerLeft, top, null);
```

So after translating the canvas, how can I can tell the canvas in the super.onDraw to use only the measured width? Please feel free to throw in any alternatives. I do want to use canvas though since my requirement is a little more complicated than this example.

Comment: I know you said you want to use canvas etc, but just to throw it in there for giggles, if you set the background of the TextView to a nine-patch-drawable, you can specify in the drawable where the Text should/shouldn't be on the X and Y axis of the drawable.

Comment: Thank you sam and I am sure I can do something using 9 patches and trust me I use them a lot. That said I also have a complex requirement and I simplified it in the question to figure out how to do it. To be frank, I asked for alternative approaches but I asked precisely what I need and mentioned that I am looking for a solution involving canvas. So your idea might work in a few cases but for me imagine that the labels are also dynamic. That is just not a good thing to do using 9-patches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I did it by changing the scale factor using canvas.scale(sx, sy) before calling super.onDraw().

This is displaying the text in the way I want. If there is a better answer, please post it.

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(margin, 0);
canvas.scale(scaleX, 1f);
super.onDraw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```